# How to remove top bar from Xamarin.Forms (iOS)?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How can I remove the top bar from iOS project of Xamarin.Forms? Where the time and "Carrier" word are

[image]

.. or at least measure its height?

Just to be sure.. I don't want to see battery, time... I want to hide the bar in the red rectangle:

[image]

Comment: You could try `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`, and a helpful link if it doesn't work as expected: [iOS NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false) not working correctly](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18450/ios-navigationpage-sethasnavigationbar-this-false-not-working-correctly)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I'm not sure, if this is "navigation bar"... I meant, the bar with the time.

Answer (score 7):

You can add this code on your `AppDelegate.cs` inside `FinishedLaunching` method **after** `LoadApplication (new App ());` on iOS Project:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = true;
```

also add this on your `info.plist`:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: in FinishedLaunching ? it doesn't look like it works :/

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood me.. I don't want to see the time - this bar

Comment: thanks! I will look at this a little bit later, will keep you posted

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Info.plist file in your iOS project
2. Click Source and Hover on one of those lines and a (+) and (-) button will show up. Click the plus button to add new key
3. Type in start with capital V and automatically the first choice will be **View controller-based status bar appearance**. Add that as the KEY.
4. Set the VALUE to "**No**"
   Now you can still see the time alone
5. Then Click again the plus button to add new key
6. Now choose **Status bar is initially hidden** and add key "**Yes**"

In case of you want to hide programatically for each page. You have to create custom renderer for each Forms Page with UIViewController.

In UIViewController, you can override method like below

```
public partial class CustomViewController : UIViewController
{
      public override bool PrefersStatusBarHidden()
        {
            return true;
        } 
}
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to hide it only on one page (the last one basically)?

Comment: @IshThomas i have updated my answer. Also if you have any difficulty in custom renderer, please refer the below to link to write custom renderer with UIVIewController for each page https://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-uiviewcontrollers-in-xamarin-forms-on-ios/

Comment: Thanks I will try that in a few, will keep you posted

Answer (score 2):

Goto info.plist

Just check the HideStatusBar

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find "Hide status bar" option.. I'm using VS 2017

Comment: @IshThomas - in VS 2017, double-click on Info.plist in Solution Explorer, to view its visual designer. At the very bottom, should show what this answer shows.