# monogame iOS show status bar / disable fullscreen

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, monogame

I am developing a game using monogame for iOS. I want to keep the status bar shown while in the game, but no matter what I try the game always launches full screen.

Things I have tried:

Unchecking 'require full screen' in info.plist

Setting graphics.IsFullScreen = false;

adding app.SetStatusBarHidden(false, false); on FinishedLaunching method on Program.cs

Does anyone know how to do this?

any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: What tutorial are you following for creating the monogame app? And have you checked this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511921/how-to-remove-top-bar-from-xamarin-forms-ios

Comment: currently not following any tutorial. This is my first iOS project with monogame but I have used it for android and desktop/GL projects previously. I have also tried the approach in the link you provided but still no luck unfortunately

Comment: What documentation are you following? Also can you please share a screenshot explaining what you’re trying to do? It seems like if you have tried all the options, there might be something else wrong